# open terminal directly point to my project folder

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I recently saw one option that we can create `Terminal` Profile.

[image]

How can I give custom path to open Terminal directly point to that path when it is open.

I want to give my project folder path so I can easily move in any project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a custom command for your profile:

[image]

The command could be something like:

```
sh -c 'cd /path/to/folder; exec bash'
```

Comment: Dangit muru !  Beaten me by a second ! And with exec too !  You're too damn good >:)

Comment: @Serg it needs the `exec`, or terminal complains when you close the tab. :/

Comment: Complains ? Doesn't do on mine Oo

Comment: @Serg for me it says there's a running process.

Comment: Ah, you mean the confirmation window ? Hmm . . . that's not that big of a deal  , at least IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options:

One, use `run custom command` option in terminal.
[image]
Two, set `cd /path/to/dir` in your `.bashrc`, preferably at the end. Every time you spawn shell, you will be automatically redirected to your desired directory

Another small hack (not the best approach, but workable): alter the shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to set it to `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir`. Check out more options that you can use when calling `gnome-terminal` manually in `man gnome-terminal`